# How To Add a button to Show/ Hide the image in webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, webview

```
 public static String getShowOrHideImage() {
    return "\n<button type='button' onclick='return showImage();' id='show-hide-button' 
    class= 'hide-or-show-text'>Hide Image</button>";
}
```

The JavaScript function

```
function showImage() {
     var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
     for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
              if (images[i].style.display === "none") {
                 images[i].style.display = "block";
                 document.getElementById("show-hide-button").innerHTML = 'Hide Image';
               } else {
                 images[i].style.display = "none";
                 document.getElementById("show-hide-button").innerHTML = 'Show Image';
               }
         }
}
```

end snippet

The function itself not invoking.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with the type.

```
public static String getShowOrHideImage() {
        return "\n<button onclick='showImage()' id='show-hide-button' class= 'hide-or-show-text'>Hide Image</button>";
    }
```